# How to nicely display Doctrine2 Exceptions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a query that output some very inconvenient error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message 'SELECT p, e, c FROM Entity\Event e LEFT JOIN e.place p
>   INNER JOIN e.categories c WITH c MEMBER OF :cat WHERE (e.dateStart
>   BETWEEN :from AND :to) AND (p.latitude BETWEEN :minLat AND :maxLat)
>   AND (p.latitude BETWEEN :minLat AND :maxLat) AND (p.latitude BETWEEN
>   :minLat AND :maxLat) AND (p.longitude BETWEEN :minLng AND :maxLng)
>   ORDER BY e.dateStart ASC' in
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39Stack
>   trace:#0
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT p, e, c ...')#1
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(528):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('':cat' is not d...',
>   Array)#2
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(233):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->_processDeferred in
>   /Users/YohannM/Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   on line 49

As you can see, this is very inconvenient for debugging as my errors are truncated: `Parser->semanticalError('':cat' is not d...',`.

I have tried to vardump the excpetion but chrome crashes as the results returned is over 1GB !!

So my question is, how do I output the errors nicely.
I'm not working with symfony2 but with Codeingniter

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use standard `try... catch...` ?

Comment: I can't vardump the exception, its too big and my browser crash. I can see there are hundreds of megabytes transfered (everytime I vardunp a doctrine entity, it crashes for no reason, I can se in the chrome console that its over 700Mb, I have no idea why)

Comment: if you want to `vardump` an exception, you should use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($object)' utility. See my answer for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `vardump` to dump an exception. Many Doctrine classes are interlinked, so, when you try to `vardump` an exception, it creates a recursion, and that is why your browser exhausts available memory and crashes.

Doctrine has a utility that allows you to dump interlinked objects and specify the level of recursion. For example, to dump an object and all linked object up to 5 levels deep use this:

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($object, 5);
```

The default depth level is 2. More info - http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Util.Debug.html